# how to run asp.net dlls?

Tags: asp.net, dll

I've got 4 ASP.NET DLLs and the source.

When i compile it it says its not able to run it because it's a class library. I know, but how should I run those files. I haven't got any aspx files or anything, just the 4 DLL's.

Comment: What are you expecting these to do?  ASP.net (i.e. the compiled libraries for a web site) aren't going to be tremendously useful without the aspx files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do these DLLs *do* that needs to be run?  Do you just need to quickly debug/test some functionality in them or something?  A quick way to do that would be to just write a simple little console app and reference the DLLs in it.

Comment: It is a full working website already. But I was asked to reverse engineer the source because they lost it. I got the four DLL's and they told me the whole website was in it. I guess I have to ask the other files.

Comment: @baklap: You'll need the ASPX files for the display code, yes.  As for reverse-engineering the DLLs, have you ever used a tool called Reflector?  It's pretty handy for decompiling .NET DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't run an ASP.NET application like you do a normal program. It has to be hosted on a web server (either IIS, or the built-in server in Visual Studio), and then accessed by a browser, through a URL.